# Rspec won't run - Error: In `bin_path': can't find executable spec for rspec-2.0.0.beta.22 (Gem::Exception)

Tags: rspec

When I run spec from the command prompt on my rails app.

> $ spec spec

I get the following error:

/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable spec for rspec-2.0.0.beta.22 (Gem::Exception)
    from /usr/bin/spec:19

However when I run

> $ rake spec

The tests run fine.

What's the issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `spec` command was renamed to `rspec` in 2.0. You're still able to run it because the 1.x Gem is still on your system, it's just "hidden" by Bundler when you specify 2.x in your Gemfile.

Comment: Yup uninstalled v2.x and left the old spec installed and got things running happily. I'll just note that while both are installed the 'rspec' is not recognised and the 'spec' command fails. Seems you can't have it both ways. Install one or the other people.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are working with outdated projects suffering from this problem, you can fix this error by doing:

```
which spec
```

Then open that file in your favourite file editor and change line 11 which looks like

```
version = '>= 0'
```

To

```
version = '< 2'
```

And your spec command will work again :)

Answer (score 0):

Run 
    $ rspec spec/

not
    $ spec spec/