# can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, react-native

This is actually a duplicate question, but I am writing in detail, so please don't close it. I have created a new project and it worked fine I run `bundle install` this command was successful. but when I try to run the command `pod install` it give me error like this.

```
mac@macs-MacBook-Pro ios % pod install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /usr/local/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    3: from /usr/local/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    2: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

So I remove the Ruby versions and then reinstall it. after that it was working fine. but after a few hours I add new dependency to my project and try to this command `bundle install` it again working fine. but then with pod install it has same issue.

Is there any fix for this?

Related questions:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673087/cant-find-gem-rspec-core-0-a-gemgemnotfoundexception-when-running-on-j)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698522/rspec-wont-run-error-in-bin-path-cant-find-executable-spec-for-rspec-2-0)